# How can i get the time of each execution in my asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net website in my local IIS and one of a page takes a very lone time(about 10 seconds) to be loaded because of a sql query(this sql query takes about 7 seconds). I did some tuning works and finally make this sql query takes less than 1 second. But the page still takes about 3 seconds to complete the loading and i think it's still slow.This page got "B" in the yslow test,so i guess there must be some CLR executions in this page takes these time,but how can i get the time of these executions(loops or variables declarations)? Is there any tool helpful? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add trace="true" to the page directive and the execution time for each phase of the page life cycle will be output underneath the page content.

[ASP.NET Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[How to: View ASP.NET Trace Information with the Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx)

Comment: Oh The Trace is cool! Thanks! I'm gonna read more details of it.

Comment: You can write to it from within page handler methods, which allows you to narrow the time window to something very specific :)